# How to check if function call has argument

Tags: javascript

Currently the  ny variable shows as defined as it is global but when i call the test function i dont want to only check if the ny argument is set. I dont want the typeof(ny) to consider the global ny variable.

```
ny = 1;
var test = function(ny){
    console.log(typeof ny ==='undefined');
}
test();
```

Comment: You could check `arguments` array in your function

Comment: your example is working on chrome

Comment: Inside test, ny will always be the local variable, even if it is not passed; if it is not passed, its value will be undefined. So this should log "true" on all browsers.

Comment: This example is working on chrome sorry for the late reply bloody net crashed\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I dont want the typeof(ny) to consider the global ny variable.

It won't. By using `ny` as an argument identifier you are shadowing the `ny` in the outer scope. Your example wil log `true`. As far as I can tell, that's what you want.

Side note: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is an operator, not a function. You don't need parentheses:

```
console.log(typeof ny === "undefined");
```

Comment: hello i ran the code in chrome typeof ny === "undefined" returns true

Comment: Yes, exactly. What are you expecting it to return?

Comment: it should return false when i call test()

Comment: Why? It is undefined because the function referred to by `test` has shadowed it, and you haven't passed in any arguments. What are you expected `ny` to contain when you call `test`?

Comment: ny is the global variable . i dont want that ny to be considered,when i check if that function has no argument

Comment: Inside the function `ny` is *not* the global variable. You have *shadowed* it. If you don't pass anything to the function, `ny` inside the function will be `undefined`. I don't really get what the problem is.

Comment: @wilsonrufus, what James means when he says 'shadowing' is that you are initiating a new `ny` variable. Defining `ny` as an argument to the function has the same effect as declaring `var ny` inside the function. The `ny` inside the function has local scope. If you want to access the global `ny` when the local `ny` is defined, refer to `window.ny`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether an argument has been passed into your function, just check the length of [the `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Consider the following function:

```
var test = function (ny) {
    console.log(arguments.length > 0);
};
```

`test()` will log `false`.

`test(ny)` will log `true`.

Comment: what if i have multiple arguments

Comment: do we get argument.name by any means

Comment: @wilsonrufus, the function I wrote only checks for the presence of arguments.  You can have any number of arguments.  For example, if you changed the console statement in the function to `console.log(arguments.length)` and then called `test(ny, 'second argument')`, the log would show `2`. You can't call the `name` property of the `arguments`, though, as that is not defined. `arguments` is an array, so you have access to all the properties of an array.

Answer (score 0):

The only ways I know:

1. Don't make global variables.
2. Don't use same variable names for differently scoped variables.

JavaScript will progressively check the scopes, expanding outwards. If you have a global variable by that name, JavaScript will eventually find it, and use it. You cannot make JavaScript ignore a variable, regardless of scope.

Comment: While the advice is sound, please note that in the example code, ny will always refer to the local variable.